# layout with symbol generates error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, layout

I have a admin namespace and Admin::UserController controller. When I try to use a layout called admin with symbol, the rails throw an exception, but if I call layout admin as a string, works sucessfull.

The exception message is the following:

**You specified nil as the layout, but no such method was found**

I just want to know why this happens...

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per here:

http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Layout/ClassMethods.html

> Sometimes you want to alternate
>   layouts depending on runtime
>   information, such as whether someone
>   is logged in or not. **This can be done
>   either by specifying a method
>   reference as a symbol** or using an
>   inline method (as a proc).

So long story short, when you specify a symbol, Rails actually expects that to be a method reference, thus the reason why it is claiming that there was no method found.